# Saving pivot with manytomany relationship in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have table below

```
User : id, name, email
Article : id, post, created_at
user_article : userid, articleid
```

table user_article is pivot table. I can save article table but how to save the pivot table.

here are my code on controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        //dd($request);

        $input = $request->all();
        $article = Article::create($input);
        $article->users()->attach($input);


        return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message', 'Article successfully added!');;

    }
```

The error said

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`user_article`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_article_articleid` FOREIGN KEY (`articleid`) REFERENCES `article` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

User Model:

```
public function articles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article','user_article','userid','articleid');
    }
```

Article Model:

```
public function users() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_article','userid','articleid');
    }
```

Can someone help on this. thank you

Comment: You wrote `$this->belongsToMany('User','user_article','userid','articleid');` Shouldn't it be: `$this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_article','userid','articleid');` ?

Comment: @El_Matellais is probably right. I recommend you use `User::class` - which returns the full namespace of the class as string instead of manually typing it in.

Comment: For many-to-many you need to define inverse ralationships, so a user `hasMany` Articles,: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many Does an article really `belongTo` many users? usually they belong to one, although it isn't a problem if that's what you need.

Comment: updated with new error ```SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blog`.`user_article`, CONSTRAINT `fk_user_article_articleid` FOREIGN KEY (`articleid`) REFERENCES `article` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)```

Comment: You need to attach your `userId` to your `article user` you are attempting to attach the entire request: `$article->users()->attach(Auth::user()->id);`